# how to log chrome app when leaving the app page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to log the activity of a chrome app, that is a new tab replacement.
 Clicking on links will make the app load the new page in the current window.  How to log such activity, console.log does not seem to do anything.
I am new to this, pls help. Google development page is not very extensive :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `console.log()` from background page and handle load every page from this code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo['status']  == 'complete'){
        console.log(tabId, changeInfo['url'], tab['url']);
    }
});
```

Comment: I still have to go back to the background page to see the log, am I right?

Comment: Yes, log will be in the background page